# How to get the last day of month (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and need to return all data with the last day of month through selected start- and enddate:

When the user select two dates something like:

Startdate: `2017-01-01`

Enddate: `2017-22-02`

The result have to be:
`2017-31-01` AND `2017-22-02`

I tried the following code, but I got the wrong result => `2017-28-02`

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0,'2017-22-02') + 1, 0)) AS DiffDate,
    MEMBER_ID
FROM 
    dbo.tblOne
WHERE
    DATUM >= '2017-01-01'
AND
    DATUM <= '2017-22-02'
```

Could anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?!

Edit:
I expect the following result:

```
    DiffDate   |  MemberID | ...
---------------------------------
    2017-01-31 |  CBK01
    2017-01-31 |  KKM05
    2017-01-31 |  ABC99
    2017-02-22 |  CBK01
    2017-02-22 |  KKM05
    2017-02-22 |  ABC99
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton Normally I always use this format `yyyy-MM-dd` but today the sql server management studio accepts `yyyy-dd-MM` only... I don't know why.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - our own, according to the wisdom of the SQL Server developers - if you `set dateformat dmy` or `set language british_english` then you'll find that it also reverses what it accepts for `nnnn-nn-nn` format. That's why, to be safe, you should use `yyyyMMdd`, that is, no separator characters (or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss` if you have a time) - SQL Server doesn't get those wrong.

Comment: I'm not at all clear on what you're trying to do here - perhaps add some *sample data* and *expected results*. Your narrative is difficult to follow.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, I edit my post.. My answer was wrong below.. I deleted it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I edited my post.

Comment: @yuro this is contradictory:  _need to return all data with the last day of month_ AND _but I got the wrong result => `2017-28-02`_. 28 Feb is the last day of month.

Comment: @AntonKruglov When you selected die Enddate by `2017-22-02` how can 28 Feb be the last day of month? ;)

Comment: @yuro Would you please elaborate as your select does not correlate with either wrong or expected result. It is unclear which is what. Which dates are parameters? How do you use last day of month (as filter? as result?)

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest this method to get last date of a month of a date:

```
declare @date datetime = '2017-04-22';

select 
    dateadd(d, 
        -datepart(d,@date)  -- count of days of @date to get back
        ,dateadd(m,1,@date) -- get date of next month of @date
    ) lastDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using UDF fn_DateSerial to simplify such date operations:

```
--sample value
Declare @Startdate datetime
set @Startdate = GetDate()

--last day of month
select DateAdd(month,  1, dbo.fn_DateSerial(Year(@Startdate),Month(@Startdate),1,0,0,0,0)) - 1
```

So basically I am striping day part (making it 1st day), then 1 month is added, and finally one day is subtracted.

This UDF was inspired by vb6 function of same name.

```
/* 
Function composes datetime from its parts - year, month, day, minute, etc.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_DateSerial(@year int, @month int, @day int, @hour int, @minute int, @second int, @millisecond int) RETURNS datetime
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dt datetime, @dtStr varchar(255)
  --mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)
  SET @dtStr = ''
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('00'+convert(varchar(2), @month),2) + '/'
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('00'+convert(varchar(2), @day),2) + '/'
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('0000'+convert(varchar(4),@year),4)

  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + ' ' + right('00'+convert(varchar(2), @hour),2) + ':'
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('00'+convert(varchar(2), @minute),2) + ':'
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('00'+convert(varchar(2), @second),2) + '.'
  SET @dtStr = @dtStr + right('000'+convert(varchar(3), @millisecond),3)

  SET @dt = CONVERT(datetime, @dtStr, 101)

  return @dt
END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is to much complicated. There is a smarter solution.

Comment: Then `select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0,@Startdate)+1,0) - 1` is way to go. It is exactly as you typed and it works. If it does not work for you - something is wrong somewhere else (not with dates).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the date format out of the solution here but that is something you really need to resolve. As I understand it you simply need to find the last day of the previous month for a given date. This will do that using getdate() as the base. You could easily change getdate() to be a column in your data.

```
select LastDayOfPreviousMonth = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```